# Taking a train at Copenhagen airport

Tags: tickets, airport-transfer, train-stations, accessibility, cph

I'm travelling to Växjö on 1st of November, arriving to Copenhagen airport in Denmark and then taking a train to my final destination in Sweden. I am a person with restricted mobility so I'm having a wheelchair assistance at the airport. I want to know how to get to the train station, where to buy train tickets, and how much walking it involves. Do I need Danish money to buy the tickets? Can I buy retour tickets to Växjö as I'm flying from Copenhagen on Monday?

Answer (score 10):

The train station at Copenhagen airport is about 75 meters straight ahead after you come out through customs. See pictures in the answer [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/88779/16947).

Access to the platform is via lifts or a set of inclined moving walkways. Trains towards Sweden depart from track 1, which is the closest to the direction you're coming from.

Right before you reach those, there is a bank of ticket machines on your right. There are ticket machines from several different agencies -- you'll want the red ones belonging to Skånetrafiken (the transit agency on the Swedish side); ask someone to help you if you're unsure which that is.

The machines accept Visa and Mastercard.

Thar are no cheaper return tickets to buy, but it ought to be easy enough to buy a ticket for the return trip at the ticket machine in Växjö.

You can also buy tickets in advance online at http://www.oresundstag.se/en/

Comment: +1 for buying tickets online. The lines at the ticket machines can be quite long and sometimes moves very slowly since most international travelers are not familiar with the machines and it takes a bit to figure it out when you do it for the  first time

Comment: Just to clarify: the machines DO NOT accept American Express.