# Plane to train transfer times at Copenhagen Airport

Tags: trains, airports, train-stations, copenhagen

I'm flying into Copenhagen from London. I'm arriving at 14:15. I'm looking to book the train from Copenhagen Airport to Linkoping. It leaves at 15:20. Let's assume the plan arrives on time.

Have I allowed enough time for the transfer?

Comment: If you decide this transfer isn't viable you can [re-book SJ tickets](https://www.sj.se/en/we-offer/tickets/rebook-cancel.html) **before** the train's departure time.

Answer (score 3):

From [Trip Advisor:](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g189541-i218-k4320238-Airport_how_long_for_checked_baggage_and_customs-Copenhagen_Zealand.html)

> Under normal circumstances baggage will be on the baggage carousel
>   maximum 30 minutes after flight arrival.
>
> Customs at Copenhagen Airport is mainly spot checks as you leave the
>   baggage claim area. There is a green channel for 'nothing to declare'
>   and a red channel if you have goods to declare.
>
> You will also have to clear immigration (I assume you will be arriving
>   from outside Schengen area). Immigration is at the end of the pier as
>   you walk from the plane to the terminal. Waiting time is normally not
>   more than 5-10 minutes, but can be 15-20 minutes if several
>   non-Schengen flights are arriving around the same time.

The UK is **non-Schengen**.

Let's say 30 minutes for baggage (and immigration)

Personally, I think this can be a bit tight, especially if there are a lot of non-Schengen flights. This could be ok if you have been to the airport before but otherwise, you don't know where everything is.

Personally I think it is doable.

Comment: Immigration is always before baggage claim, so you don't add the baggage wait to the immigration wait.

Comment: Terminal 1 in Copenhagen is for domestic flights. The OP will be arriving in terminal 2/3 (there's only a difference for check-in) from which there are no shuttles to the train station, but only ~75 meters(so any kind of shuttle would be a waste), there are pictures in the answer here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88764/finding-the-train-station-at-copenhagen-airport/88779#88779

Comment: Actually, @Henrik, there's no terminal 1 at all anymore. It closed in 2015; some of it is now the remote end of pier A.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a train that runs more often on the day and your ticket will be valid for other trains on the same day, as common in Denmark for many trains, I would not hesitate to plan on this train, knowing that a late arrival or a delay in getting out of the airport will make me an hour or two late.
On the other hand, if this is a timed ticket, only valid for the train you booked it for, and rather expensive or hard to buy a replacement ticket last minute, I would want to plan for a later train.

A 14:15 arrival from London quite likely means that your plane will have to arrive to London from some other place and that makes delays in departure more likely but in no way sure. Add to that the chance your own flight can be delayed even when the plane comes in on time.
With your time table you may be able to soak up to 30 minutes of delay if you are lucky on everything else. The chances on delays with your flight and within the airport that exceed half an hour are quite high but on the other hand, early arrivals and speedy routes through the immigration and customs process are not unheard of.

It is up to you whether you are willing to take that risk.
(I have not flown to Copenhagen but the times in the answer by @Xnero fit with the times I have seen in other EU airports for London to Schengen flights.)

Comment: Linköping is quite a distance up in Sweden (more than halfway to Stockholm, in fact), so the train the OP has in mind will not be one of the local _Øresundståg_, but an _SJ Snabbtåg_ where tickets are tied to a particular departure.

Comment: In that case I would go for an earlier flight, a later train or even an overnight stay in Copenhagen.

Answer (score 3):

I'm intimately familiar with this airport and the train station below as this is my "home" airport. I find this connection uncomfortably tight.

Risks in this itinerary:

- your flight may be late
- you are coming from outside Schengen so you have to go through immigration (and if applicable: need to use the slower non-EU lane)
- if you have luggage, this airport can be very slow to deliver it (it usually takes mine *at least* 30 minutes to appear) — but this is not additive to the time you'll spend in immigration
- you might be randomly stopped by customs on your way out (it does happen, from personal experience)
- if it is the first time you are in CPH, you might find the layout a bit confusing and lose precious minutes wondering if you are really going the right way towards the luggage belt or realize that you ended up in the the wrong train platform

If your flight is on time, immigration is fast and you don't have any luggage, it *is* doable but that is a lot of *if*s. I strongly suggest that you take a later train, and if you are early just relax and have a beer (or your beverage of choice) in the airport.